# How React/Javascript detects if property is accessed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I found very very interesting situation in ReactHookForm library. It took me a while to detect this strange behavior.

When I destruct `isValid` property (and not call/use even!) and type something in input, `validate` method is called on every key press. But when I do not destruct it, it behaves like it should - triggers validation on blur. How is that possible that destructing of object calls some action?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-async-field-validation-forked-j89s3m?file=/src/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Controller,
  FormProvider,
  useForm,
  useFormState
} from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const Input = () => {
  //   const { isValid } = useFormState(); // magic

  const { errors } = useFormState();

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="username">User Name</label>
      <Controller
        defaultValue=""
        name="username"
        rules={{
          validate: async (value) => {
            console.log(
              "why it is logged when isValid is returned from useFormState?"
            );
            await sleep(1000);
            return value === "bill";
          }
        }}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <input
            onChange={field.onChange}
            onBlur={field.onBlur}
            value={field.value}
            name="username"
            placeholder="Bill"
          />
        )}
      />
      <input type="submit" />
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  const methods = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    reValidateMode: "onChange"
  });

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={console.log}>
        <Input />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}


**Edited:**
This magic is a Proxy object :)
```

Comment: Please add the code directly to the question itself. Sandbox links are nice to have, but they cannot replace a [mre].

Comment: @InSync updated

Comment: No magic. Just a getter.

Comment: I read is Proxy object. Thanks